# Exporting Data via URL(REST API) from IBM MobileFirst analytics v 7.0.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I need to export data for various event types via URL(REST API) which can be manually downloaded from analytic console. (Administration -> Export Data).
These event type includes "Custom Activity", "Server Logs" etc as given in Event Type drop down.

I found the API documentation is available for  IBM Mobile First Platform version v7.1.0 and was able to export it via URL in v 7.1.0.

**For v 7.1.0**
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_raw_reports.html

But When I moved to IBM Mobile First Platform version 7.0.0, I did not find similar API exposed to export these event type data similar to v 7.1.0.

**for v 7.0.0**
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_raw_reports.html

If any one tried to export data for various event types in v 7.0.0 via URL(API), please help with any documentation or exact URL which can be used to export this data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is working in 7.0:

curl -XGET -G 'http://:/analytics-service/data/exportData/apps/worklight/export' --data-urlencode 'query={"level":"*","server":"*","format":"csv","timeInterval":"day","timeAmount":-50,"startDate":1475269200000,"endDate":1482271200000,"event":"server_logs","limit":10,"offset":0,"tenant":"worklight"}' -u admin:admin -o export.csv

Note the URL is: /data/exportData/apps/worklight/export

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help, I have couple of questions on this   1) Is there any documentation available for this if yes can you provide the link?

Comment: 2) Can you help me to export data for "custom_activities" similar to "server_logs" as I tried with this URL but not got any data.http:///analytics-service/data/exportData/apps/worklight/export?query={"mfpAppName":"","server":"","format":"csv","timeInterval":"day","timeAmount":-50,"startDate":"*","endDate":"*","event":"custom_activities","limit":10,"offset":0,"tenant":"worklight","mfpAppVersion":"","deviceOS":"","deviceOSversion":"","deviceModel":""} I think I am passing wrong parameters can you help me to identify the right parameters for custom activities?

Comment: 3) What does timeInterval, timeAmount(in negative)  means? as I did not see these query parameters in v 7.1.0 and did not found any documentation available to explain these parameters.

Comment: Really appreciate if you can help me in above comments.Thanks