# Only 10 results in IBM Analytics Console (MobileFirst) custom charts export

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

I'm trying to export more than 10 results in the IBM MobileFirst Analytics Console, but I don't know how to configure it before I use the export action. I was reading some [documentation about it](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_exporting_data.html) but is very superficial.

I'm building a custom chart in table format, and I want to export all the pages, 5 pages with 25 rows each in total.

Is this possible in a non programmatic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while I was writing this post, a friend of mine was helping me to look for the solution and here is:

In the custom charts section we can locate a link button in the upper right corner of each chart. This option can generate a URL with some parameters in a GET petition style. We can add a **limit** parameter with the rows number that we want to display in the export output trough the browser.

For example:

http://:/analytics-service/data/custom/apps/worklight/export/?format=json&startDate=*&endDate=*&**limit=30**

I want to reference two answered questions related:

- [How to configure IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 analytics console REST API maximum search result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176530/how-to-configure-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-8-0-analytics-console-rest-api-maximum)
- [Exporting Data via URL(REST API) from IBM MobileFirst analytics v 7.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234764/exporting-data-via-urlrest-api-from-ibm-mobilefirst-analytics-v-7-0-0)